# Async PNG saving is sometimes so slow

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, save, png

In an image editor saving realtively large PNGs is slow, so I used AsyncTask to save in background after activity is paused (closed). It's working perfectly usually. But sometimes ( maybe after keeping app in background for hours and then bringing app to foreground) the saving is delayed, maybe 20 seconds after I close the activity.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    savePngAsync();
}

public void savePngAsync() {
    int theBitmapW=Math.max(png_width,MAX_DRAWN_X);
    int theBitmapH=Math.max(png_height,MAX_DRAWN_Y);

    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(theBitmapW, theBitmapH, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    drawOnCanvas(canvas,true,false);
    String outputfilename=filename+".png";

    AsyncPngSaver asyncPngSaver=new AsyncPngSaver(outputfilename);
    asyncPngSaver.execute(bmp);
}

public class AsyncPngSaver extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Integer,Boolean>
{
    public String outputfilename;

    public AsyncPngSaver(String outputfilename)
    {
        this.outputfilename=outputfilename;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream out=null;
            Bitmap bmp = bitmaps[0];
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(outputfilename);
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
                // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        Log.d(Utils.DTAG,"png saved in background, broadcasting");
        Intent in = new Intent(Utils.KEY_REFRESH_BROADCAST);
        getContext().sendBroadcast(in);
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use service instead of asynctask?

Comment: @AjayShrestha Thanks, do you know any tutorial?

Comment: `saving realtively large PNGs is slow`. No. Messing around with large bitmaps is slow. You are saving bitmaps to begin with. `saveBitmapAsPngAsync()`.

Answer (score 0):

you don't care about the transparency, then please use 
Bitmap.Config.RGB_565

it will be fast!!!

Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

Comment: Actually I do care about transparency, because paper color is selectable :)